# How to store value as a static when data is come from long press gesture in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

My app is running and tap the long press gesture and take a value from a `textField`. I want to store this data as a static and when I stop the app this data will be a store in an app. once again run the app and tap the long press then give the different value and this value will be changed with previous static data, next data will be a store. If don't tap the long press then previous data will not be lost.

**Example:**

App is running and tap a long press and give the input and store it like

```
  Static NSString *ab = @"something";
```

Now this is my static data and its used when app is running then I stop the app and runs once again

Tap a long press and give the input like:

"anything"

this data is changed with previous data.

so, now

```
Static NSString *ab = @"anything";
```

how is it possible?

Comment: is there any datasource of random words in your app ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to save this in [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults?language=objc)

```
static NSString* const TextFieldKey = @"TextFieldKey";

...

// Saving.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:TextFieldKey];

...

// Restoring.
textField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:TextFieldKey];
```

Please read about [`static` variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable).

Please study Apple's iOS Programming Guides before posting more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSUserDefaults`. Value is saved in it until you delete the app.

and will not change value unless you update it.

Try this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
```